# Why where not exists return exist ids?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my query:

```
select a.id, a.affiliation 
FROM public.affiliation AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ncbi.affi_known1 AS b 
  WHERE  a.id = b.id
)
limit 5000
```

it returns:

| id | affiliation |
| --- | --- |
| 4683763 | Psychopharmacology Unit, Dorothy Hodgkin Building, University of Bristol, Whitson Street, Bristol, BS1 3NY, UK. |

as first row.

but

```
select * from ncbi.affi_known1 where id = 4683763
```

do return the data with `id  = 4683763`

both id are int8 type

table a

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."affiliation" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "affiliation" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "tsv_affiliation" tsvector,
  CONSTRAINT "affiliation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
;
CREATE INDEX "affi_idx_tsv" ON "public"."affiliation" USING gin (
  to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, affiliation) "pg_catalog"."tsvector_ops"
);

CREATE INDEX "tsv_affiliation_idx" ON "public"."affiliation" USING gin (
  "tsv_affiliation" "pg_catalog"."tsvector_ops"
);
```

table b

```
CREATE TABLE "ncbi"."affi_known1" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "affi_raw" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "affi_main" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "affi_known" bool,
  "divide" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "divide_known" bool,
  "sub_divides" text[] COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "country" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  CONSTRAINT "affi_known_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
;
```

update:

after create index on id, everything works well.
delete the index, it seems go wrong.
so why primary key id fails there.

update2:

table b is generated from table a, using:

```
query = '''
    select a.id, a.affiliation 
    FROM public.affiliation AS a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (


     SELECT 1
      FROM ncbi.affi_known AS b 
      WHERE  a.id = b.id
    )
    limit 2000000
    
'''   
data = pd.read_sql(query,conn)

while len(data):
    for i,row in tqdm(data.iterrows()):

        ...


        curser_insert.execute(
            'insert into ncbi.affi_known(id,affi_raw, affi_main ,affi_known,divide,country) values ( %s,  %s, %s,%s,%s,%s) ',
            [affi_id,affi_raw, affi_main, affi_known,devide,country]
        )
        conn2.commit()
        

    conn2.commit()
    conn.commit()
    data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

and the code exit improperly.

Comment: Show a runnable test case with the behavior you reported.  Adjust this fiddle, as needed: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2ff373a9902d7e37dbe8184efcce655

Comment: What is the data type of `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of how `EXISTS` works might be off.  Your current exists query is saying that id `4683763` exists in the `affiliation` table, *not* the `affi_known1` table.  So, the following query should return the single record:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.affiliation 
FROM public.affiliation a
WHERE a.id = 4683763;
```

Comment: I want ge record in table a, not in table b.

Comment: affi_known1  are generated from table affiliation

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the requirement is to fetch rows only when the id is not present in the second table, so you can try this

```
select a.id, a.affiliation 
FROM public.affiliation AS a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM ncbi.affi_known1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` were an integer, your query would do what you want.

If `id` is a string, you could have issues with "look-alikes".  It is very hard to say what the problem is -- there could be spaces in the `id`, hidden characters, or something else.  And this could be in either table.

Assuming the ids look like numbers, you could filter "bad" ids out using regular expressions:

```
select id
from ncbi.affi_known1
where not id ~ '^[0-9]*$';
```

Comment: both id are int8